# Is making a different models for different categories is good, Django?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I'm making a website that provides services

Shall I create different model for different type of service available.

Like class service:
name:
description:

class hotel service:
service=foreign (service)
check-in
Checkout

class delivery service:
location
from:

Like this???

Answer (score 0):

in this case, whenever you need a new service you have to create a new model in your project, which is not good!

instead, you can make two models `Service` and `Attribute`.

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

class Attribute(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.TextField()
    value_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=[])  # choices will be like string, boolean, date etc.
```

so when you need a new service, make an object of service model like `hotel service`, then create related attributes for that service like `check_in`, `check_out` etc. you need to cast your attribute value base on the value type.

in this approach, you no longer have to change the codebase to create a new service.

you can also make `attribute.name` a foreign key to `AttributeName` model to cut off name redundancy.